# Gatsby Styled Components , CSS is displaying in <head>

Tags: gatsby, styled-components

I'm building a Gatsby website with styled components.

Here's my problem. When I create a component with styled components like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Test = () => {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

export default Test

const Wrapper = styled.section`
h1 {
    font-size: 300px;
}
`
```

Result:
The CSS is getting displayed in the `<head>` tag. On the image below you can the see the CSS displaying on the top left.

[image: gatsby styled components error]

I'm using the latest version of Gatsby and my package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-hello-world",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simplified bare-bones starter for Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "0BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.13",
    "gatsby": "^2.29.2",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.8.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.11.2",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.9.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.2.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

I haven't found anything on google relating this issue. Did anybody run into the same problem before? Do you need to see some other code? Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve never used Gatsby before, but AFAIK it could depend on your constants’ order (cfr. https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/styled-components/). Try this:

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const Wrapper = styled.section`
    h1 {
        font-size: 300px;
    }
`;

const Test = () => {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
          <h1>Test</h1>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

export default Test;
```

This *should* work. You may always want to set a more specific constant for `<h1>`.

Comment: I've tried your approach but its not working. Super weird error lol.